# Upon bootup, screens stay black SOMETIMES (windows issue?)

Tags: windows, boot, video, multiple-monitors, blank-screen

**Sometimes** after booting up windows, my screens will just stay black. They do have a signal, but its just backlit black. No mouse cursor. No input reaction.

There is no rhyme or reason to it, there is no trouble shooting. Just reboot and hope. Nudging cables or card seating never have any effect and seem solid anyway.

*Related to this: Sometimes one screen is detected but the other one is not detected, even though nothing changed. There is nothing you can do while the PC is running. No settings will detect the missing screen, even unplugging and replugging does nothing. Sometimes this persists after reboot and I need to remove power for a few seconds and try again.*

I cannot confirm this on linux, I havent booted up into it often enough. I think it hasn't happened there.

In this rig the screens are connected via HDMI and display port.

*Interesting note*: I had this behavior with almost every rig build I ever did (windows). This spans over a decade and different technologies like AGP back in the day. Sometimes using multiple video cards, sometimes one.
So to my anecdotal experience it seems to be a common issue.

Comment: I have had something similar, which seems to be a power issue where either the PSU is not delivering enough juice or is of a cheaper brand and somehow sometimes has, sometimes not has enough juice. After I replaced my PSU with a much better one, the problem never came back. Keep in mind, you do not need to match the power requirement of the system, it can go much higher, only not lower. So if you estimate your system to require 450Watt, its okay to get an 800 to 1200Watt PSU.

Comment: Definitely possible. However I can always see the bios booting, it just goes black once the OS takes over. Also I never had any voltage issues, seemingly, while heavy load/gaming.
Apartments that I lived in also usually have no grounded outlets, which results in things like noise for audio recording, but not sure it would be related here.

Comment: No ground can definitely be an issue here.